# My images are not shown in php

Tags: php

Hi I'm new to PHP and I've tried online docs for writing syntaxes for displaying images in web browsers.
When I try this code:

```
echo '<img src="/netbeans/PhpProject2/Plate.jpg" alt ="Test" />';
```

I'm able to see the images in the web browser but when I try the alternative one:

```
$image_address = "/netbeans/PhpProject2/Plate.jpg";
echo '<img src=$image_address alt ="Test" />';
```

I'm not able to see anything ! I also tried:

```
echo '<img src="$image_address" alt ="Test" />';
```

and

```
echo '<img src='.$image_address.' alt ="Test" />';
```

but nothing happened ... what's wrong ....? how can I put the address in a variable and then show it in the web browser ... I know that my address should begin from the localhost...

Comment: Make sure your images path is correct, as starting with */* locates on */* directory of your server or PC.
then try `echo '<img src="'.$image_address.'" alt="Test" />';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround it by double quotes instead of single quotes.

```
echo "<img src=$image_address alt ='Test' />";
```

That is because variables will not be parsed inside single quotes.

You could alternatively use these too..

```
echo "<img src=".$image_address." alt ='Test' />";
echo "<img src='$image_address' alt ='Test' />";
```

Comment: May I know which one ? I tested all these on PHPStorm.

Comment: what does dots do in .$variable. ?

Comment: It concatenates the variable to the string. (_Like a sticker_) :)

Answer (score 1):

The best syntax for this would be:

```
echo "<img src='{$image_address}' alt='Test' />";
```